# KeyError 0 loc selection with string in pandas

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

A friend sent me this dummy code, in order to do a simple cypher :

```
chaine1="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
chaine2="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
list1=list(chaine1)
list2=list(chaine2)
rnd.shuffle(list2)
code=pd.DataFrame({"Key": list1, "Value" : list2})
```

He managed to recover one letter like this :

```
a = code.loc[code['Key'] == 'a', 'Value']
```

So he tried to iterate over the word to encode it :

```
word1="helloworld"
for char in word1:
    h=code.loc[code['Key'] == char, 'Value'][0]
```

The syntax looks the same but it failed :

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-4e2a59e0978e> in <module>()
      1 word1="helloworld"
      2 for char in word1:
----> 3     h=code.loc[code['Key'] == char, 'Value'][0]

~/Envs/test_bapt/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    599         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    600         try:
--> 601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    602 
    603             if not is_scalar(result):

~/Envs/test_bapt/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2475         try:
   2476             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2477                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2478         except KeyError as e1:
   2479             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4404)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4087)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5126)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:14031)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13975)()

KeyError: 0
```

I figured out that `.values` was missing : `h=code.loc[code['Key'] == char, 'Value'][0]`.
But does someone know why the first line worked ? I thought that iterating over a string would still return a string. Maybe I am missing something and it comes from pandas. I am running version `'0.20.3'`

**EDIT :** When I posted I forgot `[0]` in the definition of `a` it should be :

```
a = code.loc[code['Key'] == 'a', 'Value'][0]
```

I am sorry completely eluded the point of my post. I wanted to understand why it worked in this simple case, and not during the iteration.

Comment: Your question has been answered, but note that using a `pandas.Dataframe` is useless in this particular case. A `dict` would probably be the best way to go (with `code = {k: v for (k, v) in zip(list1, list2)}`).

Comment: I totally agree, I would have gone with a `dict` instead. But I wanted to understand why the simple case fail, see my **EDIT** at the bottom of my post. Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FabianP pointed out in the comments:

> iloc is not needed here. The slice used with loc already returns one character (as a series), so here [0] tries to index the character, which is not iterable

It does not return an array, therefore when you are slicing using '[0]' you do not require the first element, but it is rather an index-based slicing -because the object is a `pd.Series`. The fact that it worked for the char 'a' is due to the fact that 'a' is the first letter of the `liste1` hence its index is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the [0] at the end of the h attribution:

```
import random as rnd
import pandas as pd

chaine1="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
chaine2="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
list1=list(chaine1)
list2=list(chaine2)
rnd.shuffle(list2)
code=pd.DataFrame({"Key": list1, "Value" : list2})

word1="helloworld"
for char in word1:
    print(char)
    h=code.loc[code['Key'] == char, 'Value']
    print(h)
```

I added two prints to make sure the code really did what he was supposed to, I get the following results:

```
h
7    e
Name: Value, dtype: object
e
4    m
Name: Value, dtype: object
l
11    t
Name: Value, dtype: object
l
11    t
Name: Value, dtype: object
o
14    j
Name: Value, dtype: object
w
22    d
Name: Value, dtype: object
o
14    j
Name: Value, dtype: object
r
17    i
Name: Value, dtype: object
l
11    t
Name: Value, dtype: object
d
3    f
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

Comment: I agree with your method, I just made a mistake copy pasting the formula for `a`, which changed my question. Please see my **EDIT** in the post.

Answer (score 1):

What if your return is not labelled "0", then you re coming back with a key errors.   For instances your return is something like this:

```
4    a
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

Then, yes you are getting a keyerror.  In Pandas, you want to do an [iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) for integer position for find the first record.   Use `.iloc`:

```
word1="helloworld"
for char in word1:
    h=code.loc[code['Key'] == char, 'Value'].iloc[0]
```

---

```
word1 = 'helloworld'
encoding=[]
for char in word1:
    h = code.loc[code['Key'] == char, 'Value'].iloc[0]
    encoding.append(h)
enc = ''.join(encoding)
print(enc)
```

Output:

```
uayyzvzeyf
```

Comment: `iloc` is not needed here. The slice used with `loc` already returns one character (as a series), so here `[0]` tries to index the character, which is not iterable.

Comment: @FabienP are you sure?  You try removing the .iloc from the above code?

Comment: Yes, and it works (`pandas 19.2` here, and not talking about the `encoding` part, which is an elaboration but not requested to answer the question). See the answer of @Erlinska for an example. If you try `code.loc[code['Key'] == 'b', 'Value'] * 2` you will just get `<series_index> <char><char>`, as expected for a `string` manipulation (but inside a pandas series).

Comment: Well, I was wrong in my first comment, `[0]` does not slice the character but the pandas series, `code.loc[code['Key'] == 'a', 'Value'][0]` will work as the series index is `0` and `code.loc[code['Key'] == 'b', 'Value'][1]` will work too as in this case the index is `1`. But if the slice does not match the index of the series, it results in a `KeyError`.

Comment: @FabienP that is why I choose to use .iloc[0] to get the first row no matter what the index label is.